# Sencha Touch - XML Reader issue

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying some basic application on Sencha Touch 2.

Instead of `json`, I am trying to read an `xml` in the sencha touch list.

I have my store defined like this,

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.store.ListStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        fields: ['id','name','email'],
        proxy: {
           type: 'jsonp',
           url: 'users.xml',
           reader: {
              type: 'xml',
              record: 'user',
              rootProperty: 'users'
           }
        },
        autoLoad:true,
    }
});
```

and my `xml` file is located at the same place where my store is.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Ed Spencer</name>
        <email>ed@sencha.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Abe Elias</name>
        <email>abe@sencha.com</email>
    </user>
</users>
```

and my list view goes like this,

```
var listStore = Ext.create('MyApp.store.DStore');

Ext.define('MyApp.view.NavigateView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'navigateview',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.store.ListStore'
    ],
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        scrollable: true,

        items: [
            {
                  xtype: 'list',
                  title: 'List',
                  id: 'datalist',
                  onItemDisclosure: true,
                  store: listStore,
                  itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{name}</div>',
            }
         ]
     }
});
```

but no o/p is shown.

Where am I doing wrong ? Please suggest!

Comment: A couple of questions, are you running this on a webserver, localhost or such? And what can you see in the safari debug console (right click, inspect element then look at console). There should be an error message there. Also read here: http://robertdougan.com/posts/how-to-debug-sencha-touch-2-applications-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues. Your XML is not valid, it needs to be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Ed Spencer</name>
        <email>ed@sencha.com</email>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Abe Elias</name>
        <email>abe@sencha.com</email>
    </user>
</users>
```

The other issue is you shouldn't create your store like that. Either specify it in the stores array and refer to it via the store id in your list or create the store like:

```
store : {
    xclass : 'MyApp.store.ListStore'
}
```

Also, I have an eye for extra commas... bad extra comma! It's at the end of autoLoad : true

Comment: Thanks for your response! Tried all these stuff, still no o/p :(